# React - why is my code inside .then not reached after making an api request onsubmit?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setstate after making an api call. however, my code is not reached after. Any idea why? Thanks!!

```
const App = () => {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(true);
    const onSubmit = () => {
        return API.updateSomething(updateProps)
            .then(() => {
                //this here doesnt get executed anymore
                setDisplay(false)
            })
    }
}
    return (
        <>
            <TextInput
                value={report}
                onChangeText={(value) => setReport(value)}
                //...
            />
            <Icon.Button
                name="report"
                onPress={onSubmit}
            >
        </>
        
    )
}
```

Added my api request:

```
    updateSomething: (updateProp) => {
        return axios.post(`${api_root_url}/report`, updateProp)
    }
```

Comment: What is `API.updateSomething`?  Does it return a `Promise`?  Is it failing in some way?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: That depends on how you `API.updateSomething` function looks like. Or if it throws an exception  - .then method will not be called. Can you append the code of it to your question?

Comment: Are you sure that onSubmit is even executed? share code of function `updateSomething`

Comment: the API.updateSomething doesnt throw any error and works fine. please see my edit, i included my api request

Comment: and yes onsubmit is executed as my api request is being made. it is only that my code inside the .then is not being executed

Comment: Can you please include response from api, like status code, payload, etc, you can find it in network tab of the browser dev tools. Also the version of axios you have.

Comment: i am using react native, axios ^0.27.2, so there is no payload on the frontend as its not a get request but post and on the backend (using nodejs) the object (here called updateProp) is received and saved into my db

Comment: Sorry, missed about native, my bad, but the question mostly is about what kind of response your API sends back to your app, even if API is only saving something and not returning data back - it still needs to return status 200 OK to indicate the request is successful to the caller. If it does not return a response - .then will not be fired but probably exception will be thrown with request timeout (if it is configured, which is by default usually). Or it will just hang forever.

Comment: ahhh I did not know but it of course makes sense that I have to at least send a status otherwise i never created a promise so .then is not being executed!!Thank you so much!!